# How does Angular modify the DOM?

Tags: angular, mutation-observers

Imagine this template...

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="random"></li>
</ul>
```

...and a MutationObserver "listening" to its changes:

```
observer.observe(this.el, { characterData: true, subtree: true });
```

Now every time this template renders, the observer reacts correctly.
But it does *not*, when I modify the content "by hand":

```
this.el.innerHTML = "<li>Another item</li>";
```

This is probably because Angular has much more clever ways to modify the DOM.

But just how exactly does Angular do it - in one line of code? Especially that "characterData" changes are getting triggered?

Comment: If you're using a framework that has been made to handle DOM changes, I don't see the point of watching the DOM changes by yourself ...You have plethora of ways to listen for DOM changes in Angular, consider using one instead of a mutation observer.

Comment: characterData is triggered when you assign to an element's text or attribute node's *nodeValue* - this is a more performant way of changing DOM compared to innerHTML, especially on low-end devices i.e. mobile browsers.

Comment: @wOxxOm exactly what I was looking for - thank you! If you make this your answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @wOxxOm said if you use `characterData: true` option then the changes will be only triggered if you assign to an element's text node's nodeValue

Angular uses #comment node for embedded views.

[image]

And angular assigns some meta information to this node

[image]

which causes the changes in MutationObserver  to be triggered.

Comment: So it's coincidentally that the `characterData: true` is triggered? Meaning that if Angular would decide not to use the #comment anymore, the observer wouldn't react anymore?

Comment: Yes, angular consider to not use it in Angular Ivy, but it was abandoned so it's sitll going to use comment node for embedded view